# Using simplemodal with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, simplemodal

I am trying to use simplemodal to have modal popups with text in wordpress posts. I've played around with various plugins but they have specific uses (such as the contact form, or another one I saw that displays a single note you can customize).

I've tried following this tutorial: http://wordpressthemescollection.com/ajax-wordpress-post-popup-with-simplemodal-and-jquery-488.html but the instructions are not very clear for people without advanced jquery or wordpress knowledge and it simply isn't working for me. The author does not explain where you put the function, for instance.

For anyone who's gotten simplemodal working in wordpress, without developing a plugin, can you please assist? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial is a good start on a solution, but does not quite provide all of the details. There are also some changes that I would make. Here is what I would do to get it working:

- Create the Ajax Handler template and page
- Make sure the link you want to use to open the modal includes the `postpopup` class and has the post ID in the `rel` attribute.
- Create a `js/` folder in your theme directory
- Download [SimpleModal 1.4.1](http://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/downloads/detail?name=jquery.simplemodal.1.4.1.min.js) and place the file in the `js/` folder
- Create a custom JavaScript file (`site.js`) and place it in the `js/` folder
- Put the following code in `site.js`:

.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a.postpopup').click(function(){
        id = this.rel;
        $.get('http://yourdomain.com/ajax-handler/?id='+id, function (resp) {
            var data = $('<div id="ajax-popup"></div>').append(resp);
            // remove modal options if not needed
            data.modal({
                overlayCss:{backgroundColor:'#000'}, 
                containerCss:{backgroundColor:'#fff', border:'1px solid #ccc'}
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

- Add the following code to your theme's `functions.php` file:

.

```
function my_print_scripts() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        $url = get_bloginfo('template_url');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-simplemodal', $url . '/js/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.1.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.4.1', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('my_js', $url . '/js/site.js', null, '1.0', true);
    }
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'my_print_scripts');
```

---

That should get it working for you. Make sure you have the `wp_footer()` function in your theme's footer. I re-worked the way the modal window was being called so that the auto-centering of the content works.

Comment: Thanks Eric, this was very helpful and I got the simplemodal working. I do have an additional question if you don't mind. I also downloaded the OSX simplemodal theme and am trying to get it to work in this scenario. Would you be able to tell me what modifications I need to make to be able to use it here?

Comment: This is amazing -- exactly what I needed. The tutorial from Wordpress Themes Collection wasn't working for me for whatever reason.