# jQuery Cycle Plugin Not Working Inside of Modal Box (Simple Modal Plugin)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, modal-dialog, jquery-cycle, simplemodal

I'm developing a Wordpress theme that opens new posts in modal boxes instead of separate pages.

The image slideshow plugin I'm using to display images for each post ([jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)) works great when the post is on its own page, but when using the [Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) plugin, the images are shown in a list instead of a slideshow, completely breaking my layout.

Here's what a post looks like on its own (click images to advance slideshow): http://cl.ly/240c3C0i1m1o

You can click on the first thumbnail on this page see how the modal works (I haven't coded in unique URL's for modals yet): http://cl.ly/3A2J1V2q1T0P

I assume the jQuery Cycle plugin isn't working in the modal box because it applies itself to the page before the modal content is loaded by clicking a link? I really don't know.

Any help would be much appreciated. I used this answer to help me implement the modal box: [Using simplemodal with wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000404/using-simplemodal-with-wordpress/5007689#5007689). I have included some relevant code from my theme below.

This is in my header.php file:

```
<?php
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery.cycle.all.min.js', '/wp-content/themes/Goaty%20Tapes%20Theme/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('product-slideshow', '/wp-content/themes/Goaty%20Tapes%20Theme/js/product-slideshow.js');
?>
```

This is what's contained in `product-slideshow.js` (initiates the settings for cycle plugin):

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('.product-images').cycle({ 
    fx:      'none', 
    next:   '.slide',
    timeout:  0
}); });
```

I have this in `functions.php` to get the modal to work:

```
function my_print_scripts() {
        if (!is_admin()) {
            $url = get_bloginfo('template_url');
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery-simplemodal', 'http://66.147.244.226/~goatytap/wp-content/themes/Goaty%20Tapes%20Theme/js/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.1.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.4.1', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('my_js', 'http://66.147.244.226/~goatytap/wp-content/themes/Goaty%20Tapes%20Theme/js/site.js', null, '1.0', true);
        }
    }
    add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'my_print_scripts');
```

This is in my `site.js` file:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a.popup').click(function(){
        id = this.rel;
        $.get('http://66.147.244.226/~goatytap/ajax-handler/?id='+id, function (resp) {
            var data = $('<div id="ajax-popup"></div>').append(resp);
            // remove modal options if not needed
            data.modal({
                overlayCss:{backgroundColor:'#FFF'}, 
                containerCss:{backgroundColor:'#fff'}
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are initializing the cycle on document ready. You need to initialize on modal show.

Check their [documentation](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#options)

```
onShow [Function:null]
The callback function used after the modal dialog has opened
```

Something like this

```
data.modal({
  overlayCss:{backgroundColor:'#FFF'}, 
  containerCss:{backgroundColor:'#fff'},
  onShow: function (dialog) {
     $('.product-images').cycle({ 
         fx:      'none', 
         next:   '.slide',
         timeout:  0
     }); 

  }
});
```